# Why do I have multiple media servers on windows server 2012?

Tags: windows, windows-media-player, windows-server-2012-r2, dlna

### Background

I have recently installed [Windows Server Essentials Media Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40837) to enable media streaming via my home network.

I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2.

However I now have 3 media servers on my home network. Two have been created my WMP (Windows Media Player) and have the name I set "My Media Server" the other is called "Digital Media Server" and i have no idea where it has come from.

They all have the same MAC address and IP address.

### Question

Why has Windows created three media server, two seemingly duplicates. How could I remove two of them? What is the Digital Media Server?

[image: Network]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but have worked out what is happening.  The thing is it seems that when you install Windows Server Essentials Media Pack it appears to install a whole new server.  ie you now have 2 servers.

The one called Digital Media Server comes from Windows Server Essentials.  it is controlled through the Dashboard - Start > Windows Server Essentials Dashboard > Settings > Media.  On my system this one did not work so I Turned it off.

The second one comes from Server 2012R2.  it is controlled through Control Panel Network & Sharing > Media Streaming Options.  This seems to be the one linked to the local Video library.

Hope that helps.

...and a little more info for folks who have this problem.

The two servers create two different shares for storing content.
For example > Server 2012 R2 uses the user Libraries C:\Users\\Videos,
Wheras Windows Server Essentials creates shared folders at C:\ServerFolders\Videos

All in all - installing Windows Server Essentials on top of Server 2012R2 really makes a mess of Server 2012R2 and in my experience I would definitely NOT recommend it.

Comment: Yep I came to the same conclusion. This answer is better than Tim's guess, so remarking as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The other Media Server's are most likely other computers on your network that have Media Streaming enabled. Follow these steps on all of the other devices on your network and ensure that Media Streaming is disabled on all of them:

1. Open **Control Panel** and choose the **Network and Sharing Center** option. If you can't find that option, use the Search feature or change the view to small or large icons.
2. On the Networking and Sharing Center panel, click on the **Change advanced sharing settings** option (on the left).
3. On the following screen, expand the **Home or Work** section and then open the Media Streaming options (Choose media streaming options).
4. The first entry on the list will be for the current device. On the drop-down to the right, choose the **Blocked** option.
5. If you have done the above on all other devices on your network, you should only see the Server 2012 R2 Media Server on your network.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. They unfortunately are not other devices on my network. I had already disabled the 1 other device on my network. They are definitely served my my server and not any other device.

Comment: Could you possibly show a screenshot of the other Media Servers in question?

Comment: I had planned to add a screen shot, and have one saved, unfortunately and rather counter-intuitively stack don't allow you to post screen shots until you have 10 rep.

Comment: You should be able to post a link to the image using photobucket or the like.

Comment: [Screenshot](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=2c1ad15)

Comment: As far as i was aware you could only have one instance of a WMP server?

Comment: Do you mean one per device or one in an entire network?

Comment: Sorry I meant one per device.

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know, it is one per device.

Comment: If you right-click on the device and choose properties, what IP address is each device pointing to? I'd hazard a guess and say that each server is showing the local/loopback IP address (127.0.0.1)

Comment: fe80::11c8:5a9c:4632:c381%4

Comment: not sure why they are being displayed in this format? All three display this hex string.

Comment: I don't know unfortunately. You'll have to wait for someone else to provide a potential explanation.

Comment: It's okay, thank you for adding the image too.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but are there other Windows user accounts on your system? Perhaps each media server corresponds to the media library of a different user account?